# How to Redirect pages in reactjs when user succesfully logs in using passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, passport.js

Hey I am beginner in reactjs and nodejs, trying to make my first full stack app. I am using passportjs for authentication and I am successful in registering user and saving data in mongodb and authenticating the user in but the problem  I am facing is to redirect to another page in react when the user successfully logs in. I am using axios to send data to the node server. If you guys need any other file let me know

Login form

```
import React from 'react'
import {Component} from 'react';
import './login.css'
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import axios from 'axios'


class Login extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            username:'',
            password:''
        }
        this.handleUsernameChange=this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this)
        this.handlePasswordChange=this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this)
        
    }

    handleUsernameChange=(e)=>{
        this.setState({
            username:e.target.value,
        })
    }
    handlePasswordChange=(e)=>{
        this.setState({
            password:e.target.value,
        })
    }
    handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        const logindata = {
            username:this.state.username,
            password:this.state.password
        }

        axios.post('http://localhost:4002/api/login',logindata)
            .then(response=>console.log(response.data))
    }
    render(){
        return(
                <form>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Login;
```

node(passport)

```
const { request, response } = require('express')
const express=require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const registertemplatecopy=require('../models/user')
const bcryt=require('bcrypt')
const jwt =require('jsonwebtoken')
const postjobtemplatecopy=require('../models/postjobmodels')
const passport=require("passport")
const cookieparser=require('cookie-parser')
const passportLocal=require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bodyParser=require("body-parser")


require('../passport-config')(passport);

router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) res.send("No User Exists");
      else {
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.send("Successfully Authenticated");
          console.log(req.user);
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `history.push("/someroute")` after you successfully logged in.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4002/api/login',logindata)
    .then(response=>{
        if(response.status === 200) return history.push("/someroute");
        else if ...
})
    .catch(err => /* do something with error*/)
```

and in router.post("/login")

```
res.status(200).send("Successfully Authenticated").
```

You should always send statuses alongside with the content.